# Angular 13 Strange blank line at the end of the page

Tags: css, angular

I use the NGX-ADMIN template which runs on Angular 12.
Following an update to Angular 13 (and only a change in the versions of Angular), I encounter this problem, and I have no idea how to identify this type of problem.
Would you have an idea, or do you know how to identify this type of problem, the origin?

I confirm once again that it is indeed the modification of the versions of angular from 12 to 13 which generated this problem.

Same problem with Angular : 14.0.0-next.5

Link of the issue : https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/5919

```
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^13.2.5",
```

After some research the problem seems to appears from there :

```
<div class="cdk-describedby-message-container cdk-visually-hidden" style="visibility: hidden;"><div id="cdk-describedby-message-1">Sort</div></div>
```

After manually deleting this, problem is solved. But now how cna i do in order that does not appear

[image: white line at the end of the page]

[image: problem here]

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here : https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24516

If you are not using material :
Add : `@angular/cdk/a11y-prebuilt.css` into you global css style (example : style.scss)

Comment: I am using material (v15.2.9), but I was still seeing this issue. Adding the a11y-prebuilt.css import fixed the issue for me, but is that the right solution if I'm using material?